# How to use Jailbreak from java manifold library correctly for junit testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, junit

I am using java's [manifold](https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold) extension library for junit testing and i cant figure what i am doing wrong even after following exactly their [docs](https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold/tree/master/manifold-deps-parent/manifold-ext#type-safe-reflection-via-jailbreak).

```java
// My Class 
package practice_junit;

public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass()
    {

    }

    private String get_string()
    {
        return "ABCDE";
    }
}

// My Unit Test Class -- first way
package practice_junit;

import manifold.ext.api.Jailbreak;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SomeClassTest
{
    public SomeClassTest()
    {

    }

    @Test
    public void assert_equals_true_test()
    {
        @Jailbreak SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
        assertEquals("Error equals","ABCDE",sc.get_string());
    }
}

// My Unit Test Class -- second way
package practice_junit;

import manifold.ext.api.Jailbreak;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SomeClassTest
{
    public SomeClassTest()
    {

    }

    @Test
    public void assert_equals_true_test()
    {
        SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
        assertEquals("Error equals","ABCDE",sc.jailbreak().get_string());
    }
}
```

In both the cases i am getting same error log :-

```
PS C:\Users\> gradle build

> Task :compileTestJava FAILED
C:\Users\SomeClassTest.java:19: error: get_string() has private access in SomeClass
                assertEquals("Error equals","ABCDE",sc.get_string());
                                                      ^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileTestJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 9s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

I am using gradle and manifold extension dependency as `compile group: 'systems.manifold', name: 'manifold-ext', version: '2019.1.12'` from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/systems.manifold/manifold-ext/2019.1.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Java are you using?  If Java 9 or later, are you using the JPMS (modules)?  If you post your Gradle script, I can help you set it up properly. Better, [post an issue on the manifold github](https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold/issues) with a link to your project. It may be that the --module-path is not explicitly set, which is a very common problem with Gradle scripts using Java 9+.  Here's are the relevant bits:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'systems.manifold', name: 'manifold-ext', version: '2019.1.12'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    // Add manifold to -processorpath for javac (for Java 9+)
    annotationProcessor group: 'systems.manifold', name: 'manifold-ext', version: '2019.1.12'
}

compileJava {
    doFirst() {
        // If you DO NOT define a module-info.java file:
        options.compilerArgs += ['-Xplugin:Manifold']

        // if you DO define a module-info.java file:
        //options.compilerArgs += ['-Xplugin:Manifold', '--module-path', classpath.asPath]
        //classpath = files()
    }
}
```

The Manifold project tends to use Maven everywhere; the Gradle setup docs are not as polished.

Comment: your suggestion worked, the only difference, I added the ```options.compileArgs += ['-Xplugin:Manifold']``` in ```compileTestJava``` task and then it built successfully

Comment: @Scott what about java 8 setup? I couldn't find useful documentation for a basic setup for java 8 on gradle

Comment: @AhmedSaid There is setup info under the 'Build' section in the [readme](https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold/tree/master/manifold-deps-parent/manifold-exceptions#building). Let me know if you still have problems. Cheers!